# Open encrypted Bitlocker disk with recovery key

Tags: recovery, bitlocker

Suddenly my laptop stopped working and I didn't know that Bitlocker was activated and I can't recover windows because I have not access. I've read that connecting the hard disk to another computer you are asked about the unlock password and also there is this new menu called 'more options' which allows to write the recovery key but I have not such option in my Windows, why is that?

Do am I force to use a cracking password tool?

Comment: What happened just before you couldn't access the Bitlocker encrypted disk?
Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: The laptop was off and I turned it on. I was working perfectly the day before and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: This page might give you some directions: https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/unlock-bitlocker-without-password-recovery-key.html

Comment: I read that page and I got the hard disk out of the laptop and I connected it to another computer by usb, but when I click on the hard disk the panel doesn't show the item 'more options' like describe in option 2/step 3, so I can't use the recovery key, because I have no password.